# windows form creates trail on moving on desktop

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a windows form application using c#. And now when I move the that form on desktop a very large trail appears. Its like when we move any window like notepad when system is overloaded. But when system is working fine. no overload still the trail appears. which doesn't look good.
so is there any way to avoid that.
My system RAM is 2GB!

Comment: this sounds more like you don't have proper drivers installed

Comment: This often happens when I run applications via VNC and have disabled full updating of the background.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to compile it in "release"-mode and see if that makes any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use large pictures on winform?

You can try this:
Try to set the  [Double buffered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered.aspx) property of the form.

or

Maybe you can solve with this code:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
get {
CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
return cp;
  }
}
```

And finally you can try to set this property of the form : [Transparency key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey.aspx) with a color which you don't use on your form.